# Sass @forward prefix with variables is not work

Tags: variables, sass, forward

Hi i have a problem about Sass @forward.
Problem is when i try @forward prefix with variables it is not work.
example:

```
@forward 'color.scss' as red-*;
$black:#000;
@use 'forward' as f;
```

```
body{
background-color:f.red-$black;
}
```

Comment: I suggest you might watch this video on using use and forward https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CR-a8upNjJ0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forwarding prefixes are applied after the `$`.
Docs: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/forward#adding-a-prefix

```
body {
    background-color: f.$red-black;
}
```